# How do I remove something from a hash linked list?

Tags: java, hashtable

How I'm having trouble for my Java class lab. In it we make a hashtable using linked lists and one of the problems is removing an item.

So far I can go through the list and say if I find the node [do this]. I don't understand what "this" is. Am I removing the node, or the key?

`if (key.equals(pairKey)) {
[remove something]

}`

Comment: what is the code for remove something ?

Answer (score 0):

In a `HashTable` you have a single key to value mapping. So when you want to remove the key, you also want to remove your value.

Which means that you should delete the whole (current) linked list node from your list.

Comment: So previously when working with nodes inlinked lists, to remove a node, we would have the one before now point to the one after. Therefore nothing now points to the current one. Is that what I want to do here?

Comment: @Wayves exactly. It is the same concept all over again, just with the quirck that you need to find the right bucket for your key. HashTables are really simple ;-)

Comment: So for that quirk I'm going to compare the current node key to the one I want removed, and if they match, remove current?